# Could not download npm: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, aem, maven-frontend-plugin

I am not able to install npm and node when I run mvn clean install command

I get below error :

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project : Could not download npm: Could not download https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-6.14.0.tgz: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Since this is certificate related issue , I have done below steps to resolve this issue :

1. Extracted the certificate from Node site
2. Install certificate by keytool command in JDK/JRE/LIB/Security in keystore cacerts
3. Certificate installed successfully

Stil I am getting same issue. I am really not able to resolve this issue.